# Layout totally messed up in IE 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

My page works fine in all the browsers except IE 7. In IE7, the divs get go out of their place completely. I suspect its due to the usage of `position:fixed` . I tried using the proper `doctype` as many suggested and it still doesn't help. Also IE7 says its rendering in standard mode so I don't know what the issue is.
Here's the jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/FgXS4/

Comment: jsfiddle does not work in IE7

Comment: r u giving float in that div?

Comment: @mishik - jsfiddle's editing UI doesn't work in IE7, but the output page does; try http://jsfiddle.net/FgXS4/embedded/result/

Comment: Is there any use recommending to torch the IE7 users in cleansing flames? %)

Comment: No Im not giving float. Its just fixed posited according to its normal flow.

Answer (score 2):

IE7 has known serious issues with `position:fixed`.

If you need to support IE7, your best option would be to just forget about the fixed positioning thing for that browser, and let the element scroll with the rest of the page. Write a custom stylesheet that only kicks in for IE7 which overrides the standard CSS, and let IE7 users have a slightly degraded browsing experience. That's my advice for your best option.

There are hacks around that try to fix the problem, notably **[IE9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)**, which implements a whole load of patches into old IE versions to try to get them to comply with modern standards. It's a great little script. It can't do everything, and it certainly doesn't magically turn IE7 into IE9, but it might help with this issue (I know it has got patches in it that specifically deal with IE7's `position:fixed` bugs), so it might be worth giving it a go.

Your other option, of course, is to stop supporting IE7. In all honesty, this might be a good answer. The number of people using IE7 is dropping very quickly (faster even than IE6); the usage figures for it a extremely low and getting lower every month. You might find yourself doing a lot of work to fix this, and then having virtually nobody that actually benefits from it. You could save yourself a lot of time if you just drop support for IE7 altogether. If you're lucky, maybe no-one will even notice. (and even if they do notice, maybe it'll give them a nudge that they need to upgrade their browser!)

Comment: If it were upto me, I'd definitely stop supporting IE. I mean it makes sense. You have an inferior product, so you get an inferior experience. Not my problem. Though due to some company policies, I have to go with it. Ill try the IE9.js you mentioned.

Comment: @user2067771 - fair enough if you can't influence company policy. But it's worth noting that company policy has to change at some point (otherwise you'd still be supporting IE5!). Given that IE7 usage is below IE6 in many countries it may be time for a policy update. If you have any influence in that, now is the time to use it. Take a look [the stats here](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201106-201306); that ought to be enough to convince anyone that IE7 isn't worth it any more, given the amount of extra work it creates.

Comment: Thanks. Although I currently have no say in company policies, you convinced me to stop whatever little support I was offering to IE7 in my personal websites.